# Dynamic Nested Ruby Loops

Tags: ruby, api, loops, dynamic, reporting

So, What I'm trying to do is make calls to a Reporting API to filter by all possible breakdowns (breakdown the reports by site, avertiser, ad type, campaign, etc...). But, one issue is that the breakdowns can be unique to each login.

Example:

- user1: **alice123**'s reporting breakdowns are `["site","advertiser","ad_type","campaign","line_items"]`
- user2: **bob789**'s reporting breakdowns are `["campaign","position","line_items"]`

When I first built the code for this reporting API, I only had one login to test with, so I hard coded the loops for the dimensions (`["site","advertiser","ad_type","campaign","line_items"]`). So what I did was pinged the API for a report by `sites`. Then for each `site`, pinged for `advertisers`, and each `advertiser`, I pinged for the next dimension and so on..., leaving me with a nested loop of ~6 layers.

basically what I'm doing:

```
sites = mechanize.get "#{base_ur}/report?dim=sites"
sites = Yajl::Parser.parse(sites.body) # json parser

sites.each do |site|
  advertisers = mechanize.get "#{base_ur}/report?site=#{site.fetch("id")}&dim=advertiser"
  advertisers = Yajl::Parser.parse(advertisers.body) # json parser

  advertisers.each do |advertiser|
    ad_types = mechanize.get "#{base_ur}/report?site=#{site.fetch("id")}&advertiser=#{advertiser.fetch("id")}&dim=ad_type"
    ad_types = Yajl::Parser.parse(ad_types.body) # json parser

    ad_types.each do |ad_type|
      ...and so on...
    end
  end
end
```

`GET <api_url>/?dim=<dimension to breakdown>&site=<filter by site id>&advertiser=<filter by advertiser id>...etc...`

At the end of the nested loop, I'm left with a report that's broken down as much granularity as possible.

This works now since I only thought that there was one path of breaking down, but apparently each account could have different dimensions breakdowns.

So what I'm asking is if given an array of breakdowns, how can I set up a nested loop to traverse down dynamically do the granularity singularity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your JSON/GET returns exactly but for a problem like this you would need recursion.

Something like this perhaps? It's not very elegant and can definitely be optimised further but should hopefully give you an idea.

```
some_hash = {:id=>"site-id", :body=>{:id=>"advertiser-id", :body=>{:id=>"ad_type-id", :body=>{:id=>"something-id"}}}}
@breakdowns = ["site", "advertiser", "ad_type", "something"]

def recursive(some_hash, str = nil, i = 0)
  if @breakdowns[i+1].nil?
    str += "#{@breakdowns[i]}=#{some_hash[:id]}"
  else
    str += "#{@breakdowns[i]}=#{some_hash[:id]}&dim=#{@breakdowns[i + 1]}"
  end

  p str

  some_hash[:body].is_a?(Hash) ? recursive(some_hash[:body], str.gsub(/dim.*/, ''), i + 1) : return
end

recursive(some_hash, 'base-url/report?')

=> "base-url/report?site=site-id&dim=advertiser"
=> "base-url/report?site=site-id&advertiser=advertiser-id&dim=ad_type"
=> "base-url/report?site=site-id&advertiser=advertiser-id&ad_type=ad_type-id&dim=something"
=> "base-url/report?site=site-id&advertiser=advertiser-id&ad_type=ad_type-id&something=something-id"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to map your data, you can recursively map to a hash as another user pointed out. If you are actually looking to do something with this data while within the loop and want to dynamically recreate the loop structure you listed in your question (though I would advise coming up with a different solution), you can use metaprogramming as follows:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

# Assume we are given an input of breakdowns
# I put 'testarr' in place of the operations you perform on each local variable
# for brevity and so you can see that the code works.
# You will have to modify to suit your needs

result = []
testarr = [1,2,3]
b = binding
breakdowns.each do |breakdown|
  snippet = <<-END
    eval("#{breakdown.pluralize} = testarr", b)
    eval("#{breakdown.pluralize}", b).each do |#{breakdown}|    
  END

  result << snippet 
end

result << "end\n"*breakdowns.length


eval(result.join)
```

**Note:** This method is probably frowned upon, and as I've said I'm sure there are other methods of accomplishing what you are trying to do.